# Sharing Wifi access of one device with other devices through wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, router, proxy, ad-hoc-network

Im on a campingground with wifi.
I have more than two devices (notebooks, smartphone, tablets) with me.
But I only have access to wifi with either one of those devics.
I.e. If I login with device A i have Internet. If I then login with device B,
device A loses connection to the Internet.
I can connect to the wifi-network, but only access to the internet if I
enter the correct Key to a loginpage. The key was given by the campinggroundadministrators.
Is there a way to somehow give access to the other devices through the same
wlan adapter of the device which is connected to the internet?

You know, like a Proxy server?

Im using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  you are already in the camping ground with no access to a shop then you may struggle, but if you can get hold of a spare USB wifi network adaptor then you can effectively install a second network adaptor in your PC and then set up Internet Connection Sharing in Windows 7 (ICS). See [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/set-internet-connection-sharing#1TC=windows-7).

Note that:

> The Sharing tab won't be available if you have only one network connection.

So you must find a way of setting up a second network for this method to work.